# Responsive text over responsive images

Tags: css, image, responsive

I have created a table with responsive images, but have no idea how to add fixed texts over the images that stay there when the window is resized. The closest I came was by using `<p class="">` but then the text isn't responsive...

Here is the script:
https://jsfiddle.net/2vax05et/

The basic layout:

```
<div id="p-container">

  <a href="#1">
     <figure>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </figure>
  </a>

[....]

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.65em;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

div {
  font-size: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  margin-right: 8px;
}

a:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  a {
    width: calc(25% - 6px);
  }

  a:nth-of-type(2n) {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  a:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

a:hover img {
  filter:brightness(80%);
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.p a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want fixed or responsive text? Responsive text will need media queries to determine the size of the text, or javascript to find width of the container and do some math to make the text the right size.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rnxqo3n9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
  <a href="#1">   
    <figure>
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
    <p>Text</p>
  </a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
  position: relative;
}

a p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}
```

The `p element` containgin the text will expand only to the bounds of the souronding `a`.
You might consider adding appropriate Padding and Hyphanation according your needs.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 2):

Use viewport units as font-size. It will scale fluidly depending on the size of your screen.

Example:

```
font-size: 2vw
```